# Create Terrain Heightmaps - missing texture mapping (blend) settings in 2.8

Tags: texture-coordinates, height-map

In 2.79 i create terrain heightmaps via the Texture Tab (blend option). There i can change the mapping to get the Z heightmap of the mesh. That option is somehow not available in 2.8. (official release) I tried to recreate it from scratch in 2.8 nor is it available when i open the 2.79 file in 2.8. - Does anybody have an idea to solve this? Thank you in advance.

[image: settings 2.79]
[image: settings 2.8]